# How to view statistics on the programming languages ​used in gitlab in a group?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Is it possible to view the languages ​​used in a group?
I have 220 projects on GitLab and I need to collect statistics on the languages ​​used.
All I found was using the following API - https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/languages
But this only gives statistics for one project, how can I see summary statistics for all projects in a group?
Is this even possible with built-in tools?

You can write a script for accessing each project in the tgroup and collect statistics for each of them and then make it common for all projects, but is it really impossible to obtain statistics on the use of programming languages ​​in all projects at once in some standard way?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it is not possible to get languages used in a group via the GitLab API. There is the [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223065) for this purpose.